# Setting QObject ownship for QWebFrame javascript

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebkit, qtscript

I have a QObject that exists in a QWebFrame javascript environment through the addToJavaScriptWindowObject interface.  This QObject has Q_INVOKABLE methods that return more QObject pointers (like a factory) that are used within javascript.  Qt automatically turns these QObject pointer into objects that can be invoked in the calling javascript enviornment.

The issue is, I want to have javascript assume ownership of this QObject.  The current behavior is that the C++ environment retains ownership.

I've dealt with QScriptEngine directly in the past where the QObject factory object holds a pointer to the QScriptEngine object and creates new objects using QScriptEngine::newQObject with a QScriptEngine::ScriptOwnership argument.  This works perfectly.  But for the QWebFrame javascript engine, the engine is buried inside of the QWebFrame and inaccessible.

How can I return QObject's to a QWebFrame javascript environment and have javascript assume ownship of that object?